# Force GeoServer to make use of carriage return from SQL Server

Tags: geoserver, labeling, sql-server

I'm completely new to GeoServer.

In desktop GIS I can use CHAR(13) in views on SQL Server to make GIS interpret a carriage return, when I visualize a label.

Is this possible using GeoServer?

As I understand it there are possibilities directly on GeoServer, but I would like GeoServer as a default to interpret CHAR(13) delivered from SQL Server as a carriage return i.e. without having to meddle with GeoServer, as I do not have access to this particular GeoServer instance, and hence I'm forced to try to solve the problem directly on SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the way XML handles white space as they are all treated as a single space. You need to provide a cdata block containing the return char to pass it through to the renderer unchanged.